# Best way to contact Facebook App Users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have many Facebook App users but not so many on my Facebook Page. How can I contact my app users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there's a "best way" for this, it depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Check out the [Social Channels guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/) which lists the different ways that facebook enables you to contact your users.
Also, check the [Requests guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/) for more info about the requests (which are mentioned in the social channels).

Other than those channels which you need to use facebook with, you can ask for the "email" permissions from your users, persist that and then you have a way to contact your users without going through facebook.